# Why are divs with text not following inline-block pattern?

Tags: html, css

I have a series of divs that have images in them. Here's the CSS:

```
p.titles-box {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color:black;
  font-weight:300;
}
#a {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
#a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

for images in the html I do as follows:

```
<div id="a" style="background-image:url('asdfasd.png')"></div>
```

and for text I do as follows:

```
<div id="a" style="background-color:white"><p class="titles-box">WordsWordsWords WordsWordsWords</p></div>
```

And yet only the divs with text end up off-grid. Any reason why?

Thanks!

Here's a pic of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ke2g.jpg

Comment: The id value should be unique, if you want to have same format in several divs group them using a class.

Comment: If I change them to classes it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: No, it is not the answer of your question, is just an advice of how to use css properly. About your question I am trying to see what is wrong... a fiddle with your code will help a lot.

Comment: Inline block elements shouldn't contain block elements.  P is a block level element.

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for your problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the alignment of the two elements(text and none)is different.

To solve it, add `vertical-align: top;` to `#a` css.

```
#a {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This solved it! I was using "overflow:hidden", which worked in chrome but was incredibly funky in safari, but this fixed it across the board. Thanks!